# Read JSON from XML in Windows phone 7 and bind to ListBox

Tags: xml, windows, windows-phone-7

I want to get JSON data from XML response. Actually web service is returning response is as follows:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "paresh",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "jacob",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "color",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Adil color",
    }
]</string>
```

I have already referred some of the articles. And if the response was only the XML then i could have implemented as below:

```
   MyListBox.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("student")
                                          select new StudentItem
                                          {
                                              ID = tweet.Element("id").Value,
                                              Name = tweet.Element("name").Value,
                                          };
```

But here my problem is to get JSON which is inside, and also to display in ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the web method response format by decorating the webmethod with ScriptMethod attribute.
the code is just like this.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Once you will get the code in json format string, you can parse it in json.

Let me know if you have any confusion.

### Update:

So you have to remove `<string>` tag manually from [substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring) method.
Here is your code.

```
string Header = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">";
        string str = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">[{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"paresh\"}]</string>";
        string TempStr = str.Remove(0, Header.Length);
        string FinalStr = TempStr.Substring(0, TempStr.Length - 9);
```

FinalStr is your json string.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, webservice is defined by client himself and we can't change anything in web service as its already been implemented in BB, iPhone and Android so.

Comment: Your **Update** part is one of the solution. Its **working fine**. Thanx man.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use twitter's finagle written in Scala to convert the xml to json using this:

```
 val xmlResponse = <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
     [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "paresh",
          },
          {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "jacob",
           },
           {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "color",
           },
          {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "james bond",
           }
     ]</string>

  val properties = (xmlResponse \\ "string")    //parse the xml

  val responseContent = xmlResponse.toSeq.toJson.toString()
```

and you can check by:

```
  println(responseContent)
```

Before you choose finagle, try a simple example in scala, then you may want to explore the finagle library. It is useful in manipulating different kinds of response from numerous servers (email, asp.net. SQL, sms just to mention a few).

Comment: actually this webservice is already implemented in Android, iPhone and Blackberry so i can't change it now. Thats why looking for a feasible solution for WP7 app. I am newbie in WP7 world so please.

Comment: you are not changing the web service, No. You are simply manipulating the response you get after curling the web service using scala (the official language used by finagle, which can be mixed with java if you are more familiar with java)

Comment: actually i am newbie in WP7 development.

Comment: to accommodate different scenarios, you can use a switch statement which ill have different cases.

Comment: "actually i am newbie in WP7 development so." My solution is platform independent, you can use it on iPhone android windows blackberry, anything

Comment: xml parsing can never be any simpler than the example I've given you. Install scala, copy and paste my code into scale's REPL then come back to me

Comment: why should i have dependent on 3rd party tool/API/framework if it can be doable in some native way.

Comment: If you will responses in all kinds of formats, it will be useful. Judging from your response you do come across interesting ones. It can be quite hectic to manually format email response, sms response, xml response, asp.net response, SQL response, etc, but if you know your response will always be simple, give it a shot at another solution

Answer (score 0):

I would consume the initial XML as you have posted, then use a library such as [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to manipulate the XML, extract the JSON and store it in an object before binding it against your ListBox.

Here's a few key points on JSON.Net (Taken from the web site)

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
- Write indented, easy to read JSON
- Convert JSON to and from XML
- Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone

Comment: I am newbie in WP7 world so please. If this is XML only then i could have implemented as i mentioned in question. But this JSON inside XML.

Comment: And if this is the JSON only then i could have implemented: `var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(inputString)`;

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i extract JSON?